# Make button change output every 3rd click

Tags: javascript, jquery

When "button" is clicked in my script it brings back an image file ("#mypic"), a sound file ("#mysoundclip") and a class that styles a word to spell ("#picknext").

The thing is, I want the button to repeat its action 3 times before moving on to the next image, sound and style. How would I do this?

```
$('#pickNext').click(function() {
// remove the class from all td's
$('td').removeClass('spellword');
// pick a random word
var r = rndWord;
while (r == rndWord) {
    rndWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
}
// apply class to all cells containing a letter from that word
$('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').addClass('spellword');

});


var audio = $("#mysoundclip")[0];
var i  = 0;
$(".minibutton").click(function() {
var noExist = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
if (noExist && i >= 3) {
    $('#pickNext').click();
    i = 0;
} else {

    $("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
    audio.play();
    pic = $("#mypic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
    pic.show();
    $i++;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of how many times the button has been pressed using jQuery's [.data() function](http://api.jquery.com/data/).  You'd set a counter and then increment, doing things when it hits 3.  A basic outline:

```
timesClicked = $(this).data('timesClicked');
if(!timesClicked) { timesClicked = 0 } //Allow for the first time
if(timesClicked < 3) {
  //Increment the counter
  $(this).data('timesClicked',timesClicked+1);
} else {
  $(this).data('timesClicked',0);
  //Do your action
}
```

If I understand your code, it would look something like this:

```
if (noExist) {
    $(this).data('timesClicked', 0);
    $(this).click();
} else {
    timesClicked = $(this).data('timesClicked');
    if(timesClicked < 3) {
        //Increment the counter
        $(this).data('timesClicked',timesClicked+1);
    } else {
        //Reset the counter and pick new things
        $(this).data('timesClicked',0);
        $("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
        pic = $("#mypic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
    }
    //Either way, play the sounds       
    audio.play();
    pic.show();
}
```

This will allow you to add more buttons if you want to, and in any event is good coding practice.  It may be wise to also add a 'maxClicks' data attribute that is set to '3' that gets checked, so that you can vary how many clicks it needs.

Looking at the code you put up your jsFiddle, there are several things that need to be fixed.  Notably, you seem to be confusing the "type" attribute of your inputs with the id.  Each id should only be used once, you're using pickNext twice.  That will break all kinds of things.  You also are using a type of "button2", which isn't valid.  Your $('button') and $('button2') click events won't work as you anticipated, because those are looking for elements with the tag of  and .  So the first event will be fired any time any button is pressed, and the second never will.  The $('#pickNext') click event, since you're using pickNext twice, will probably only fire for the second button.  You should probably give them id's of "pickNext" and "reset", and then refer to those selectors for your click events.

Long story short: get the rest of your code working, and then worry about getting things to happen three times.

Comment: See my additions.  There's a few things broken on that page, and you're not going to get your click-three-times thing working until that's cleaned up.

Comment: But you've still got button and button2 events that aren't doing what you think they're doing, and have duplicate functionality, that will break if you try to develop this further.  Against my better judgement I've tried to clean it up myself and add my code in: http://jsfiddle.net/qBzPx/14/

But I would advise you to take some time to get a good book on Javascript/jQuery and read up on it - you'll save yourself a lot of pain going forward.

Comment: Closer.  But the $('button') event will fire any time any button is pressed, because a selector without a # (id) or . (class) before it just selects by tag name.  And you still have type="button2", which isn't a valid input type.  But they're <button>s, so they don't need a type in the first place.  Right now _both_ events are running when you press the Next button - once because it has an id of pickNext, once because it's a button element.

Comment: You have to understand what your code is doing before you can fix it properly, and you're not quite there yet.

Comment: I see what you mean now, hows this... http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/qBzPx/17/ @cincodenada

Comment: Yes, that's better.  You'll eventually have to re-implement the replay button and give its own ID, but that's cleaner for now.  You've still got two click events on your Next button though - one via the id (#pickNext) and one via the class (.minibutton).  Right now the #pickNext click event picks a new word, the .minibutton handles the sounds/images/etc.  I'd combine them into one function, and add in the counter logic.  I'm still not sure what you want to happen three times.

Comment: Thats done now. Now I want the next button to be active after the user has 3 attempts at the word. Do you know how I would do that instead of the original question? @cincodenada

Answer (score 0):

add counter:

```
var i = 0;
```

and later:

```
i++;
```

don't forget to check it :)

```
if(i == 3)
```

Comment: You can set up i as global variable and replace "i == 3" with "i % 3 == 0" for it to work with multiples of 3

Comment: In the #picknext function? @Mantas Vaitkūnas

Comment: yeap, and don't forget to reset i = 0, or do like @lukas.pukenis wrote.

Answer (score 0):

```
var audio = $("#mysoundclip")[0];
var i  = 0;
$("button").click(function() {
var noExist = $('td[data-word=' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + ']').hasClass('wordglow2');
if (noExist && i >= 2) {
    $('#pickNext').click();
    i = 0;
} else {

    $("#mysoundclip").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].audio);
    audio.play();
    pic = $("#mypic").attr('src', listOfWords[rndWord].pic);
    pic.show();
    $i++;
}
});



$('#pickNext').click(function() {
// remove the class from all td's
$('td').removeClass('spellword');
// pick a random word
var r = rndWord;
while (r == rndWord) {
    rndWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
}
// apply class to all cells containing a letter from that word
$('td[data-word="' + listOfWords[rndWord].name + '"]').addClass('spellword');

});
```